# How to set $(this) as the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code:

```
// submit an item
$(document).on("click", ".match-item", function(event) {


    // how to set $(this) == $('.match-item') clicked?

});
```

I'm looking to retrieve `$(this)` as the clicked item and not the `document` itself. How would I do this?

Comment: `this` appears to indeed refer to the clicked element? https://jsfiddle.net/eqh36m0r/

Comment: as per jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ this actually is clicked element, why don't you just use it instead of set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is more of clarification rather than answer.*

`this` is already referring to the currently clicked element.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".match-item", function(event) {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="match-item">----Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably better to ask for clarification or VTC as no-repro

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$('.match-item').click(function() {
     //your code with $(this) here
});
```

I am pretty sure `$(this)` will refer to the element with class `match-item`